# Using " echo append >> file" recursively

Tags: bash, append, echo

I want to append a line to the end of every file in a folder. I know can use

```
echo apendthis >> file
```

to append the string to a single file. But what is the best way to do this recursively?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo "append this" >> "{}"' \;
```

Comment: Just hope no files have double-quotes in their names.  A safer method would be passing the path via positional arguments: `find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo "append this" >> "$1"' _ {} ';'`

Comment: how do you do that when the text you want to add is on several lines, not just one?

Answer (score 2):

#### Literally or figuratively...

Do you mean *recusively* to be taken literally or figuratively? If you are really in search of a specifically recursive solution, you can do that like so:

```
operate () {
  for i in *; do
    if [ -f "$i" ]; then
      echo operating on "$PWD/$i"
      echo apendthis >> "$i"
    elif [ -d "$i" ]; then
      (cd "$i" && operate)
    fi
  done
}

operate
```

Otherwise, like others have said, it's a lot easier with [find(1).](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use a loop:

```
find . -type f | while read i; do
    echo "apendthis" >> "$i"
done
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this answer is recursive, since the find command will search all subdirectories. I find this usefull when several commands need to executed. But I agree that DigitalRoss's answer is true recursion.