# concatenating multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, concatenation

I have multiple files, and in each file is the following:

```
>HM001
ATGCT...
>HM002
ATGTC...
>HM003
ATGCC...
```

That is, each file contains one gene sequence for species HM001 to HM050. I would like to concatenate all these files, so I have a single file that contains the genome for species HM001 to HM050:

```
>HM001
ATGCT...ATGAA...ATGTT
>HM002
ATGTC...ATGCT...ATGCT
>HM003
ATGCC...ATGC...ATGAT
```

The ellipses are not actually required in the final file. I suppose cat should be used, but I'm not sure how. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data parsing and formatting will be alot easier with `awk`. Try this:

```
awk -v RS=">" 'FNR>1{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] FS $2:$2}END{for(x in a) print RS x ORS a[x]}' f1 f2 f3
```

For files like:

```
==> f1 <==
>HM001
ATGCT...
>HM002
ATGTC...
>HM003
ATGCC...

==> f2 <==
>HM001
ATGDD...
>HM002
ATGDD...
>HM003
ATGDD...

==> f3 <==
>HM001
ATGEE...
>HM002
ATGEE...
>HM003
ATGEE...
```

```
awk -v RS=">" 'FNR>1{a[$1]=a[$1]?a[$1] FS $2:$2}END{for(x in a) print RS x ORS a[x]}' f1 f2 f3
>HM001
ATGCT... ATGDD... ATGEE...
>HM002
ATGTC... ATGDD... ATGEE...
>HM003
ATGCC... ATGDD... ATGEE...
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. Is there a way, rather than writing out all the file names (f1,f2,f3), to concatenate all files located in folder X? I ask because there are some 1000s of files in folder X.

Comment: @user1038055 You're welcome. You can just use `glob`. Instead of writing the file names, just put `*` to reference all files in a given directory.

Answer (score 0):

What about appending them using echo - along these lines?:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo "append this" >> "$0"' {} \;
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15604608/1662973

I would do it using "type", but that is MSDOS.  The above should work for you.

Comment: `{}` is not meant do be used that way. Imagine a file named `lol"; rm -rf . ; "true`. Oooops. Instead: `find . -type f -exec bash -c 'echo "append this" >> "$0"' {} \;`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I expected as much, but I was more trying to draw attention to the echo side of it.  My Linux skills is 1.5/5 (enough to install and manage redmine on Linux AND old enough to have supported xenix :) ).  Please go ahead and edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest converting your group of files into a CSV? It's almost
exactly what you're suggesting, and is easily incorporated into just
about any application for processing (e.g., Excel, R, python).

Up front, I'll assume that all species and gene sequences are simply
alpha-numeric, no spaces or quote-like characters. I'm also assuming
access to `sed`, `sort`, and `uniq`, which are all standard in *nix,
MacOSX, and easily accessible for windows via
[msys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) or
[cygwin](http://cygwin.org/), to name two.

First, generate an array of file names and species. I'm assuming the
files are named `file1`, `file2`, etc. Just adjust the first line
accordingly; it's just a glob, not an executed command.

```
FILES=($(file*))
SPECIES=($(sed -ne 's/^>//gp' file* | sort | uniq))
```

This gives us one line per species, sorted, with no repeats. This
ensures that our columns are independent and the set is complete.

Next, create a CSV header row with named columns, dumping it into a
CSV file named `csvfile`:

```
echo -n "\"Species\"" > csvfile
for fn in ${FILES[@]} ; do echo -n ",\"${fn}\"" ; done >> csvfile
echo >> csvfile
```

Now iterate through each gene sequence and extract it from all files:

```
for sp in ${SPECIES[@]} ; do
    echo -n "\"${sp}\""
    for fn in ${FILES[@]}; do
        ANS=$(sed -ne '/>'${sp}'/,/^/ { /^[^>]/p }' ${fn})
        echo -n ",\"${ANS}\""
    done
    echo
done >> csvfile
```

This works but is **inefficient** for larger data sets (i.e., large
numbers of files and/or species). Better implementations (e.g, python,
ruby, perl, even R) would read each file once, forming an
internally-maintained matrix, dictionary, or associative array, and
write out the CSV in one chunk.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is to use cat. For example (assuming you're on a *nix-type system):

```
cat file1 file2 file3 > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk implementation:

```
awk '
    {key=$0; getline; value[key] = value[key] $0} 
    END {for (key in value) {print key; print value[key]}}
' file ...
```

Now, this will probably not output the keys in sorted order: array keys are inherently unsorted. To ensure sorted output, use gawk and

```
awk '
    {key=$0; getline; val[key] = val[key] $0} 
    END {
        n = asorti(val, keys)
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {print keys[i]; print val[keys[i]]}
    }
' file ...
```